# Disable 'JSFL script running for a long time' prompt

Tags: flash, adobe, jsfl

I am using JSFL as a tool for creating levels in my game. Generation of big levels takes quite a lot of time but that OK. Problem is that every 1-2 minutes execution stops and Adobe shows this annoying message about my script taking too long to finish. And I have to sit and click 'Continue' over and over again until the script finishes it's actual work. Is there a way to disable this prompt message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.

```
fl.showIdleMessage(false);
```